# How to speed up my import from excel file to sql database in MVC C#

Tags: java, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, file-upload, epplus

I am using entity framework and mvc c# to extract data from excel file into  sql table the problem is that I am looping through about seventy thousand records so I would like to know how I can speed up the process. I dont think my for loop is smart enough there are too many lines of code and perhaps that is why the processing is slow. I am sure there is a smarter and faster way. I have pasted my for each loop below

```
 public ActionResult Upload(FormCollection formCollection)
            {
                var usersList = new List<marketingdbclients_tempDataTable>();
                if (Request != null)
                {
                    HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files["UploadedFile"];
                    if ((file != null) && (file.ContentLength > 0) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(file.FileName))
                    {
                        string fileName = file.FileName;
                        string fileContentType = file.ContentType;
                        byte[] fileBytes = new byte[file.ContentLength];
                        var data = file.InputStream.Read(fileBytes, 0, Convert.ToInt32(file.ContentLength));
                        using (var package = new ExcelPackage(file.InputStream))
                        {
                            var currentSheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets;
                            var workSheet = currentSheet.First();
                            var noOfCol = workSheet.Dimension.End.Column;
                            var noOfRow = workSheet.Dimension.End.Row;
                            for (int rowIterator = 2; rowIterator <= noOfRow; rowIterator++)
                            {
                                var user = new marketingdbclients_tempDataTable();
                                user.FirstName = ConvertToString(workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 2].Value);
                                user.MiddleName = ConvertToString(workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 3].Value);
                                user.LastName = ConvertToString(workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 4].Value);
                                //user.
                                user.RaceId = ConvertToString(workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 6].Value);
                                user.DateOfBirth = ConvertToString(workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 7].Value);
                                user.Age = ConvertToString(workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 8].Value);
                                user.TitleTypeId = ConvertToString(workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 9].Value);
                                user.Nationality = ConvertToString(workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 10].Value);
                                user.PhysicalCountry = ConvertToString(workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 11].Value);
                                user.PhysicalProvince = ConvertToString(workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 12].Value);
                                user.PhysicalCity = ConvertToString(workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 13].Value);
                                user.Area = ConvertToString(workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 14].Value);
                                user.HighestQualification = ConvertToString(workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 15].Value);
                                user.CurrentQualification = ConvertToString(workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 16].Value);
                                user.PhysicalAddress = ConvertToString(workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 17].Value);
                                user.Cell1 = ConvertToString(workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 18].Value);
                                user.Cell2 = ConvertToString(workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 19].Value);
                                user.Cell3 = ConvertToString(workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 20].Value);
                                user.Cell4 = ConvertToString(workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 21].Value);
                                user.Work1 = ConvertToString(workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 22].Value);
                                user.Work2 = ConvertToString(workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 23].Value);
                                user.Work3 = ConvertToString(workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 24].Value);
                                user.Work4 = ConvertToString(workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 25].Value);
                                user.Home1 = ConvertToString(workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 26].Value);
                                user.Home2 = ConvertToString(workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 27].Value);
                                user.Home3 = ConvertToString(workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 28].Value); ;
                                user.Home4 = ConvertToString(workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 29].Value);
                                user.LSMGroup = ConvertToString(workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 30].Value);
                                user.Municipality = ConvertToString(workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 31].Value);
                                user.Crediting_Rating = ConvertToString(workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 32].Value);
                                user.Email1 = ConvertToString(workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 33].Value);
                                user.Email2 = ConvertToString(workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 34].Value);
                                user.Email3 = ConvertToString(workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 35].Value);
                                user.Email4 = ConvertToString(workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 36].Value);
                                user.Income = ConvertToString(workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 35].Value);
                                user.Company = ConvertToString(workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 36].Value);
                                user.Industry = ConvertToString(workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 37].Value);
                                user.JobTitle = ConvertToString(workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 38].Value);
                                user.LeadStage = ConvertToString(workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 39].Value);
                                user.ReggieNumber = ConvertToString(workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 40].Value);
                                user.Source = ConvertToString(workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 41].Value);
                                //user.SNo = Convert.ToInt32(workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 1].Value);
                                //user.Name = workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 2].Value.ToString();
                                //user.Age = Convert.ToInt32(workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 3].Value);
                                usersList.Add(user);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                //MarketingDBEntitiesModel db = new MarketingDBEntitiesModel();
                using (MarketingDBEntitiesModel excelImportDBEntities = new MarketingDBEntitiesModel())
                {
                    foreach (var item in usersList)
                    {
                        excelImportDBEntities.marketingdbclients_tempDataTable.Add(item);
                    }
                    excelImportDBEntities.SaveChanges();
                }
                return View("Index");
            }
public string ConvertToString(object value)
        {
            try
            {
                return value.ToString();
            }
            catch
            {
                return "Null";
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This will get slower and slower since the DbContext will be tracking each entity as you save it. Break it up into chunks of 500-1000 rows read from excel and inserted via a DbContext, but be prepared to handle exceptions.

These two lines don't look to be necessary:

```
byte[] fileBytes = new byte[file.ContentLength];
var data = file.InputStream.Read(fileBytes, 0, Convert.ToInt32(file.ContentLength));
```

You're basically reading the entire file into memory, but later using a `InputStream` for the Excel read.

Instead, use the Input stream to read 1000 rows into objects, then add the rows into a disposed (/w `using` block) instance of the DbContext with a single `SaveChanges()` call. You'll need to handle the exception given that if any 1 row fails, that block of 1000 will not be persisted.

For large operations like this, I wouldn't process the file as part of the web request, but rather persist the file on the server, create a record in a Processing Queue table with the file location and a pending status, and return the page. A background worker process can poll the Processing Queue, pick up the file and process it completely in the background, updating the status on the record. Your web UI can poll the queue record to report on whether the queue has started processing and track progress as you see fit. The main issue with processing the request in-line like this is that it will require a good chunk of CPU and memory and there is nothing stopping multiple users from kicking this action off. With a Queue, even if you get 100 requests, they will only be processed as fast as the queue worker (or coordinated between workers) which will limit the impact on available resources.